# Passport + Express - User Sessions Conflicting

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a simple Node+Express application with Passport Local authentication, it's working nearly perfectly (the right pages are served up, login/logout works, etc).

One issue though is that if a second user logs in, that session "takes over" the first user's session and suddenly the first user is now logged in as the second user!

This is almost certainly an issue with the order of the middleware, but I haven't been able to find it - I'm fairly new to Passport and Express.  The code is taken liberally from docs and examples, but I might have messed the order up.

I've followed the order in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781294/passport-js-passport-initialize-middleware-not-in-use) but it's still not working.  Can anyone suggest where I might be mixed up?

The main server:

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var Strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var url = require('url');
var db = require('./db');

// Configure the local strategy for use by Passport.

passport.use(new Strategy(
  function(username, password, cb) {
    db.users.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      if (!user) { return cb(null, false); }
      if (user.password != password) { return cb(null, false); }
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  }));

// Configure Passport authenticated session persistence.

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {    
  console.log('DEBUG: serializeUser called ' + user.id);    
  cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {    
  console.log('DEBUG: deserializeUser called ' + id);    
  db.users.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return cb(err); }
    cb(null, user);
  });
});

// Create a new Express application.

// Use application-level middleware for common functionality  (Order is important!)
// Initialize Passport and restore authentication state, if any, from the session.

var app = express();

app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'qwerty', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));  // Step 2.
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); 


app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login.html' }),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('Logged In: ' + req.user.username);
    res.redirect('/');
  });

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){

    if (req.user != null) {          
        console.log('Logged Out: ' + req.user.username);
        req.logout();    
    } else {
        console.log('Warning: null user logging out');
    }

    res.redirect('/login.html');
});

app.get('/user', function(req, res){   
    if (req.user != null) {          
        res.send(req.user.displayName);      
    } else {
        res.send('ERROR: No current user?');
    }
});

function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {

    if (req.user) {   // User is logged in
        return next();
    }

   if (req.url.startsWith('/login')) {   // Allow login through to avoid infinite loop
       return next();
   }

   res.redirect('/login.html');
}

app.use('/', isAuthenticated, express.static('/public/'));
```

The db/users.js file:

```
var records = [
    { id: 1, username: 'jill', password: 'birthday', displayName: 'Jill'}
    { id: 2, username: 'jack', password: 'hello',    displayName: 'Jack'}
];

exports.findById = function(id, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    var idx = id - 1;
    if (records[idx]) {
      cb(null, records[idx]);
    } else {
      cb(new Error('User ' + id + ' does not exist'));
    }
  });
}

exports.findByUsername = function(username, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    for (var i = 0, len = records.length; i < len; i++) {
      var record = records[i];
      if (record.username === username) {
        return cb(null, record);
      }
    }
    return cb(null, null);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tumbleweeds!

So it turns out that it was working fine - the problem was just that Chrome reuses its session across tabs.  I found a helpful comment buried in this question's answer.  One login from Chrome and another from IE works fine, no conflict.

[Node + Passport - multiple users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139283/node-passport-multiple-users)